# Is there a name for a design pattern that abstracts network communication?

Tags: design-patterns

I have an interface that some components rely on:

```cs
interface IFoo {
  void DoWork()
}

class Component() {
  void Method(IFoo f) {
    f.DoWork();
  }
}
```

as well as a concrete implementation of the interface.

I want to abstract away the network communications from the components so that they can either be used either as a fat client or thin client, so I have written a sender/receiver pair that implements and contains the interface respectively:

```cs
class Sender : IFoo {
  void DoWork() {
    // do network stuff to send message
  }
}

class Receiver {
  IFoo f = ...
  void Recieve (...) {
    f.DoWork();
  }
}
```

Is there a named design pattern that describes the above abstraction and design? It looks a little bit like an adapter pattern but it is not changing the interface. The receiver by itself could be implemented as a decorator, but that does not describe the sender, or how the two are used in conjunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do reminds me of Stubs and Skeletons. Take a look at.

- [Stub and Skeleton Layer](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/rmi/1500-stub-skeleton-layer.html) which is a special case of
- [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)

Does it match your problem?

Comment: The `Sender/Receiver` pair is almost an example of Stub and Skeleton Layer. An interesting difference is that my `Receiver` has an `IFoo` but in your SaSL `Receiver` is an `IFoo`.

Comment: Yes, your propossed pattern is a little odd. You have a ``Sender`` which calls the ``Receiver`` and the the ``Receiver`` calls the ``Sender`` in return, which again calls the ``Receiver`` and so on. So you have modelled a symetric alternating communication, with an asymetric implementation. Not sure why you modell the ``Sender`` different from the ``Receiver`` while both do basically the same stuff, namely calling the other one.

Comment: Not quite - the `Receiver` has an `IFoo` which is (probably) not a `Sender`. There are other implementations of `IFoo`.

Comment: In this case you can leave out the ``Receiver``, since it's only responsibility is to delegate to ``anotherFoo``. This is the ``Middle Man`` code smell. Calling ``anotherFoo`` directly leads to the Stub and Skeleton Layer Pattern again.

Comment: I disagree with you. The responsibility of `Receiver` is to abstract away all the communication logic and then pass on the call. I think that putting all the communication logic in the `anotherFoo` would introduce the coding smell of having too many responsibilities.

Comment: I'm not that experianced with Network communication, but in my experiance the Server-/Networking technology handles all the Communication logic of your ``Receiver``. For Java EE there is the ``web.xml`` to specify which method to call on which class. Webservices also handle this logic for you as far as I know.

Comment: How your ``Receiver`` is build seems to be an technology specific problem, and should thus not be a part of an design pattern. If you don't have a choice about the interface of the ``Receiver`` and have to implement the ``Receiver`` yourself (i.e. it's not part of your framework), then your approach is a good work around to overcome that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I think that given the motivation, the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern  (in particular the [class variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern#Class_Adapter_pattern))is what you want. One adapter can execute the code locally, while anonther Adapter implementation makes a remote call.

I don't fully agree with Waog answer as the motivation of the patterns he mentions is quite different. And also the Adapter pattern goes together with the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to allow different low level implementation to be swapped.

Comment: I think I disagree. The link that you posted contains "The adapter pattern is useful in situations where an already existing class provides some or all of the services you need but does not use the interface you need." The concrete `IFoo` implements the right interface, but is providing the service in the wrong place.